# Starting deallocated VMs (3-6) with azure cli takes around half an hour

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I wrote a shell script which contains a azure cli command and want to start deallocated VMs identified by its tag. The machines are started after short time (around 1-2 minutes) but the command keeps going and finishes after around half an hour.

The command looks like this:

```
az vm start \
  --ids $(az resource list \
  --tag "environment=$env" \
  --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'].id" \
  -o tsv)
```

when in debug mode, I see that it repeats this block all over:

```
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: urllib3.connectionpool : https://management.azure.com:443 "GET /subscriptions/****/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/westeurope/operations/hduske73-sg43-156df-afg4-4jefasfgs?api-version=2019-03-01 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger : Response status: 200
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger : Response headers:
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Expires': '-1'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Retry-After': '9'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-resource': 'Microsoft.Compute/GetOperation3Min;14997,Microsoft.Compute/GetOperation30Min;29997'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-request-id': '3876g8d-h383-d8eh-h482-dhu372dfg'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads': '11938'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-correlation-request-id': 'dh3819874-4fb4i3-1435-5215-behxb3819'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-routing-request-id': 'GERMANYNORTH:20191031T091214Z:dh3819874-4fb4i3-1435-5215-behxb3819'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger :     'Date': 'Thu, 31 Oct 2019 09:12:13 GMT'
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger : Response content:
00:00:27.352  DEBUG: msrest.http_logger : {
00:00:27.352    "startTime": "2019-10-31T09:12:02.7728761+00:00",
00:00:27.352    "status": "InProgress",
00:00:27.352    "name": "efu2728392-38f9-2a24-24d2-c214152g1245"
00:00:27.352  }
```

Can anyone help me finding the issue?

Comment: update az cli and try again, try from another workstation, etc. this is probably something with your az cli

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same that the VMs are started in a short time but the command keeps running for a long time with azure-cli `2.0.75`. It seems that the command is designed to just loop around the ID array not go parallel.

MSFT has a clarification about it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7069#issuecomment-413692977).

> It is by design right now as the core layer just loops around the id
>   array and invoke the same command one after one. Agreed we should
>   improve it by going parallel. The REST call is io-bound, so doing
>   parallel would get commands way faster.